# How to render create view when model has reference to another model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC. Currently I want to render a create page of a model, which has reference to another model, and make user select the other model  from drop down list. To be more specific, here is the code for `Category` model

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code of `Food` model

```
public class Food
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Consider I have an in memory list of categories called `categories` and I want to make sure that when I send create view to user with `return View();` in `HomeController`'s `Create` method he gets not only the name to choose but also the drop down of `categories`. Also consider that in near future I want to generate the tables of database according to these classes (Entity Frameworks code first approach) so adding properties to the classes doesn't seem like a good idea.
How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried, and what is not working? Suggest you refer the code in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for example of how to generate a dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of viewBag to pass more than one model from controller to view like this

**Controller**

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{  
 viewbag.Childone=Childone();
 viewbag.Childtwo=Childtwo()
 return View(parentModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ParentModel parentModel,Childone child_one ,Childtwo child_two)
 {
  //do something with models passed....
 }
```

**View**

```
 @model parentModel

 @{
    Childone  = viewbag.Childone as Childone;
    Childtwo  = viewbag.Childtwo as Childtwo;
  }

   //just use these models......like
 //this is Main parent model
 <p>@Model.propertyname</p> 

   //these are child
 <p>@Childone.propertyname</p>

 <p>@Childtwo.propertyname</p>
```

**On Model Submit Button Click**

```
var parentModel = [
  { id: 1, color: 'yellow' },
 ];
 var child_one = [
    { id: 1, color: 'yellow' },

];   

 var child_two = [
    { id: 1, color: 'yellow' },

];      



$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/Index',
    data:JSON.stringify(parentModel:parentModel child_one:child_one,child_two:child_two),
    success: function () {          

    },
    failure: function (response) {          

    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to not use javascript and just send both classes to server without it.